# Java Unit Test Mock HttpServletRequest getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, junit, mockito

How to mock `HttpServletRequest` `getResourceAsStream` in a Java unit test? I am using it to read a resource file from a servlet request.

`HttpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream()`

I am using `org.mockito.Mock` to Mock `HttpServletRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is quite a bit of mocking you need to do. I would suggest using annotations:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class TestClass{

   @Mock
   private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequestMock;

   @Mock
   private HttpSession httpsSessionMock;

   @Mock
   private ServletContext servletContextMock;

   @Before
   public void init(){
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void test(){
       // Arrange
       when(httpServletRequestMock.getSession()).thenReturn(httpSessionMock);
       when(httpSessionMock.getServletContext()).thenReturn(servletContextMock);

       InputStream inputStream = // instantiate;

       when(servletContextMock.getResourceAsStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);

       // Act - invoke method under test with mocked HttpServletRequest

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockHttpServletRequest servletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        servletRequest.setRequestURI("/Turmo/");
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(servletRequest));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please explain your solution.